# Override ENV['HOME'] for development of a Ruby command line app

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I'm building a Ruby command line application with the following characteristics:

- It uses the [GLI](https://github.com/davetron5000/gli) framework.
- The app utilizes the `ENV['HOME']` variable for the path to the user's home directory.
- The configuration file is stored under the user's home directory.
- The app will be deployed to production as a Gem.
- Development is done on the same machine that uses the app in production.
- A combination of Cucumber, RSpec and running the app via `bundle exec bin/app_name` are used to test the script in development.

The app manipulates files. My goal is to ensure the development instance only operates on its own dev/test environment. I believe a good approach is to override `ENV['HOME']` when the script is being run for development.

Is there a way to override the `ENV['HOME']` variable so that, regardless of how, whenever the script is run in its development directory it doesn't use the actual `ENV['HOME']` path?

Comment: Do you have in mind a way to determine whether the script is the development version or not?

Comment: @matt, that's part of the trick I'm trying to figure out. (I'm relatively new to this type of stuff in Ruby.) I'm thinking I could have a file that acts as a switch that exists in dev, but isn't deployed to production. I'm working on experiments with that approach now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this would be to keep any development specific stuff out of the actual application code, but to have a `Rakefile` to use for testing during development. In there you could make sure the environment is set up appropriately, something like:

```
desc "Run the app"
task :exec do
  ENV['HOME']= "somewhere else"
  exec "./bin/your_binary"
end
```

You would then run `rake exec` (or give the task a better name) to run the development version, whilst still being able to run the real version. If you keep your development `bin` directory of your `PATH` there shouldn’t be any chance to mix up the two commands.

If you do want to be able to run the development version directly you could use the fact that when you run a gems binary the actual file that is executed is the wrapper file that Rubygems creates. You could check for this with the `__FILE__ == $0` idiom in the top of your executable:

```
if __FILE == $0
  # executing directly, probably in dev environment
  ENV['HOME'] = "somewhere else"
end
```

When calling your file directly the environment will be replaced, when calling an installed gem `$0` will be the wrapper file so the original environment will be used.

The “normal” way to do this is to just set the environment from your shell, e.g. in Bash:

```
$ HOME='somewhere else' ./bin/the_executable
```

The danger here of course is that you might forget to set the environment, causing you to trash some of you files. You could get round that by setting the new environment for your whole seesion:

```
$ export HOME='somewhere else'
$ ./bin/the_executable
```

but this will likely effect other tools that use `HOME` so it’s not advisable.

My advice would be to go for the Rakefile option, with the `__FILE == $0` option as second choice.

Comment: I'm working on this approach. Also, for some cases, I'm adding in a check for a file that would only exist in the dev environment. It's effectively a kill switch if that file exists and ENV['HOME'] hasn't been updated. If I don't accidentally trigger it for a while, I'll remove it, but for now, I like the idea of the extra layer of protecting me from myself as I learn Ruby.